# Navigation is not called right after user is unauthenticated

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to logout the user and then send him to SignedOut screen but when I press on Sign Out it is calling the `unauthUser` function but then it restart the switch navigator to dashboard and I have to go in profile screen to tap again on Sign Out to go out. Any idea what am I doing wrong in all this?

Here is my button from Profile.js

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => onSignOut().then(() => {
     this.props.dispatch(unauthUser)
     navigation.navigate("SignedOut")
     }
  )}
>
    <View style={styles.signOutButton}>
        <Text style={styles.button}>SIGN OUT</Text>
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

`onSignOut()` from Auth.js

```
export let USER_KEY = 'myKey';

export const onSignIn = async () => { await AsyncStorage.setItem(USER_KEY, 'true') };
export const onSignOut = async () => { await AsyncStorage.removeItem(USER_KEY) };

export const isSignedIn = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem(USER_KEY)
      .then(res => {
        if (res !== null) {
          // console.log('true')
          resolve(true);
        } else {
          resolve(false);
          // console.log('false')
        }
      })
      .catch(err => reject(err));
  });
};
```

`unauthUser` from authActions.js

```
exports.unauthUser = {
  type: 'UNAUTH_USER'
}
```

and from authReducer.js

```
case 'UNAUTH_USER':
  return {
    user_id: undefined,
    token: undefined
};
```

and here is my switch navigator

```
export const createRootNavigator = (signedIn = false) => {
return SwitchNavigator(
    {
      SignedIn: {
        screen: SignedIn
      },
      SignedOut: {
        screen: SignedOut
      }
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: signedIn ? "SignedIn" : "SignedOut"
    }
  );
};

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      signedIn: false,
      checkedSignIn: false
    };
  }

  async componentWillMount() {
    await isSignedIn()
        .then(res => this.setState({ signedIn: res, checkedSignIn: true}))
        .catch(err => alert("An error occurred"));
  }

  render() {
    const { checkedSignIn, signedIn } = this.state;
    // If we haven't checked AsyncStorage yet, don't render anything (better ways to do this)
    if (!checkedSignIn) {
      return null;
    }

    const Layout = createRootNavigator(signedIn);
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ffffff'}}>
          <StatusBar barStyle="light-content"/>
          <Layout />
          <AlertContainer/>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
};
```

Comment: How are you deciding the value of `signedIn` passed to `createRootNavigator`? Can you please share some code where from you have called `createRootNavigator` function.

Comment: @PrasunPal please have a look now

Comment: Can you please check after removing the bracket from `onSignOut`, like `export const onSignOut = async () =>  AsyncStorage.removeItem(USER_KEY) ;`

Comment: @PrasunPal it is still same. The thing is if I put a `console.log` after `navigation.navigate("SignedOut")` it gets printed out but the function is not called

Comment: Can you please check what value your are getting in `signedIn` inside `App.render` function, It is the `signedIn` value which controlling the switching. BTW can you please share implementation of `isSignedIn()`?

Comment: @PrasunPal I just updated my post please look on Auth.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171096/discussion-between-prasun-pal-and-markus-hayner).